# calculations in function seem to be ignored, same number returned always

Tags: c++

**growthRate function:** (as of 8:00 PM 12/11/2010)

```
    #include "header.h"

float growthRate (float birthRate, float deathRate)     
{   
    float growthrt;  
    growthrt =  (birthRate) - (deathRate);
    cout << growthrt << endl; 
    return growthrt;

}
```

**estimatedPopulation function:** (as of 8:00 PM 12/11/2010)

```
#include "header.h"

float estimatedPopulation (float currentPopulation, float years, float birthRate, float deathRate)
{
    int x;
    float newPopulation;
    for (x = 0; x < years; x++)
    {
    newPopulation = currentPopulation + currentPopulation * (growthRate (birthRate, deathRate) / 100);
    currentPopulation  = newPopulation;
    cout << newPopulation << endl;
    }

    return newPopulation;
}
```

**output function:**(as of 8:00 PM 12/11/2010)

```
#include "header.h"

void output (float currentPopulation, float years)

{     
     cout <<  estimatedPopulation (currentPopulation, years) << endl;
}
```

**main function**:(as of 8:00 PM 12/11/2010)

```
#include "header.h"

int main ()
{

    float currentPopulation, birthRate, deathRate, years;

    char response; 


     do //main loop
      { 
           input (currentPopulation, birthRate, deathRate, years);
           growthRate (birthRate, deathRate);
           estimatedPopulation (currentPopulation, years, birthRate, deathRate);
           output (currentPopulation, years, birthRate, deathRate);
           cout << "\n Would you like another population estimation? (y,n) ";
           cin >> response;
      }          
    while (response == 'Y' || response == 'y');

    myLabel ("5-19", "12/09/2010");   

    system ("Pause");

    return 0;

}
```

**edit (8:00 PM 12/11/2010)**

Solved! parameters, parameters, parameters! thanks for the input everyone.

Comment: Can you give us example values for `birthRate`, `deathRate`, `currentPopulation`, and `years`?

Comment: birthrate and deathrate can be any percentage rate. currentpopulation is just a number for the population. and years is going to determine the amount of time the for loop in the estimatedPopulation function will execute. You want me to actually tell you my input and then results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see a problem with this code?

```
void output ()

{
     float currentPopulation, years;

     cout <<  estimatedPopulation (currentPopulation, years) << endl;
}
```

If you really can't see why this is wrong, then you should start off with MUCH simpler programs.

Comment: Do you understand what I am trying to do though? I just want to output whatever is returned from that function. I Just don't know how to pass them around correctly. Do I need to put currentpopulation and years in the parameter for output?

Comment: It's somewhat clear what you want to do, but there's not really a single piece of your code that's correct. Start with a SINGLE function an first see how function calls work. It's pretty obvious that you've never gotten a program to compile/run correctly before. Start simpler.

Answer (score 3):

You have two main problems.

The first problem is that your return value from `estimatedPopulation` is an `int`. So when the result of your expression is evaluated, it is converted to an `int`, which will round it down. Unless the result of `currentPopulation * growthrt / 100` is greater than one, you'll never see a change. Same issue with your last example I think.

The other problem is that you keep assigning the same value to the `newPopulation` variable. You probably want to adjust `currentPopulation` within the loop.

@Matt: it looks like you're not using your return values from your function, e.g.:

```
something = estimatedPopulation(currentPopulation, years);
```

(By the way - that function is supposed to take 4 parameters???)

And be aware that when you pass in an 'int' that variable within the function is local to the function - modifying it will have no effect on the variable of the same name outside the function. It looks very much like this is what you're expecting to happen. If you do want to modify the value you pass in, you might try something like:

```
void estimatedPopulation(int &newPopulation....) {
```

This passes the variable in *by reference* so that you can actually modify it within the function.

Comment: good call. I added currentPopulation = newPopulation; in the loop but oddly it is still not changing its value.

Comment: @Matt: Did you try making `newPopulation` a `float`?

Comment: yup, made everything float for now.

Comment: @Matt: maybe you should start checking for alternate versions of your files, object file output, or includes.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing updating `newPopulation` or `currentPopulation` as the loop iterates, so `newPopulation` is just getting overwritten several times with the same value.  I imagine at some point in that loop you want a line like `currentPopulation = newPopulation;`

EDITED TO ADD:

Now that you added your `main` function:  You are treating all of your function calls as though they were of type `void`.  That is, you aren't actually using any of the return values from `estimatedPopulation` or `growthRate`, so I am honestly surprise you are getting anything but garbage values printed in your `output` function, as its argument is never set.

Comment: right, currentPopulation = newPopulation; has been added. still no update occuring.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing newPopulation as a parameter but by value, not by reference, or a pointer. So its not updated by your code.

You are also not touching that variable, so it will just do one iteration.

Comment: It's a useless parameter which should be changed to a local variable, and ditto for `growthrt` in the first function

Comment: fixed iteration issue. Not sure what you mean about passing newPopulation as a value but not by reference.

Comment: @Ben, actually, wouldn't I need to keep growthrt  as a parameter of the growthRate function since it is used in the estimated population function?

Comment: @Matt: no, it's the return value from the `growthRate` function.  You are saving the return value somewhere when you call it, right?

Comment: @Ben, hmm, dont think so. How would I save it?

Comment: In your main function, you'd have a line that looks something like `float growthrt = growthRate(birthrt, deathrt);`

Comment: No, posted my main for you. I have prototype statements for my functions in a header file. is that what you mean?

Comment: @Matt I think you are confused about how functions communicate with each other. You give information to a function, normally, by passing it in parameters, and you get information back by returning a value. You use the returned value at the point where you called the function, basically as if the function-call were magically replaced by the result of calling the function. Thus if you have a line like `float growthrt = growthRate(birthrt, deathrt)`, what happens is that `birthrt` and `deathrt` are copied over to the function, which calculates and returns a value, which is assigned to `growthrt`.

Comment: @Karl I think i was too! see my edit, how does my usage look now?

Comment: Better, but you still need to trace the logic and make everything flow properly. Rule of thumb: if you're calling a function that returns something, you probably should be using what it returns right away. Your main loop doesn't generally do this. Also, there should only be one place that is outputting results; right now you do it both via `output` in the main loop, and directly within `estimatedPopulation`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what everyone else said, it looks like `growthrt` is being divided by 100 twice, once inside function `growthRate` and again inside your loop in `estimatedPopulation`.

Another thing you're going to run into as soon as you get things updating is that the loop runs `years+1` times, which may be more than you want.

Comment: Thanks for spotting those issues. If I just make x = 1 that should solve that issue right?

Comment: @Matt: Yes it would, but the more traditional way is to say `for( x = 0; x < years; ++x )` (notice `<` instead of `<=`).  Loops in C and C++ (and Java, and C#) usually start at zero because arrays in these languages start at zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a case of rounding with ints, say "currentpopulation" is 100,  "growthrt" is 0.1. then: the sum becomes:
`100 + 100 * 0.1 / 100 = 100.1;` - This then however is set as the next "newPopulation". Yet since new population is an integer, it is rounded down to 100 again!

Better change "newPopulation" to a double/floating point number (and maybe at the end of the function round it down again)